# Separate 0 from None

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to implement next situation in my save function in model: if `factor_rate` exists in database ( `not None`) -> than do something. But in my case `0` is acceptable value for me, user can provide this value in form. And I don't know how to separate None from 0. Do you have any idea?

```
if self.factor_rate:
    self.status = False
else:
    self.status = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check with `is None`:

```
if self.factor_rate is None:
    self.status = False
else:
    self.status = True
```

or shorter:

```
self.status = self.factor_rate is not None
```